# Download file from URL and upload it to AWS S3 without saving into memory using AWS SDK for Java, version 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, inputstream

I am writing a code that will download a file from URL and upload it to S3, but I don't want it to be stored temporarily in file or memory, I am downloading through 'InputStream' but AWS s3 requires the file size which I don't have from 'InputStream' is there any other way.
[I found the this discussion on same topic using 'Node.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186979/download-file-from-url-and-upload-it-to-aws-s3-without-saving-node-js)

---

My Code to Fetch the file in inputStream

---

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
URI uri = URI.create("{myUrl}");
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri).build();
InputStream is = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()).body();
```

---

Code I tried to insert into S3, but I don't have content_length

---

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();
PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                            .key(KEY)
                            .build();

PutObjectResponse por = s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromInputStream(is,content_length));
```

Comment: I don't know If it is related or not, but using 'S3AsyncClient' for 'AsyncRequestBody' there is no method 'fromInputStream()', I didn't found why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

The easiest is to retain the `HttpResponse` from your `client.send()`, and get the `Content-Length` header from it. You should also be looking for headers like `Content-Type`, and storing them as metadata on the S3 object.

That isn't guaranteed to work in all cases: some servers do not provide `Content-Length`. In that case you need to create a [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) to send the file. When doing this, you buffer relatively small chunks (minimum 5 MB) in memory but can upload up to 10,000 chunks. You *must* either complete or abort the upload, or configure your bucket to delete uncompleted uploads after a certain period of time; if not, you'll be charged for incomplete uploads.

A third alternative is to use the V1 SDK, which gives you `TransferManager`. That handles the multi-part upload for you, and uses multiple threads to improve bandwidth. But it still hasn't been implemented for V2.

Answer (score 1):

"Code I tried to insert into S3, but I don't have content_length"

To get around having to have content length - instead of using an InputStream that does require the content length, you can use a btye[], as described here.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/RequestBody.html#fromBytes-byte:A-

Getting a byte array depends on the application you are building. For example, some apps, the byte array can be created from a file being posted to a web app. Other apps, a byte array can be created from a file that is read at a certain location. The point here is your app has to get a byte array somehow and use that data to upload content to an S3 bucket.

If you app has an InputStream (*which it seems you have based on your thread description*), convert that to a byte[] using Java logic. Once you have the byte[], you can call **putObject**, as shown here.

```
public String putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {

        s3 = getClient();

        try {
            //Put a file into the bucket
            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName)
                            .key(objectKey)
                            .build(),
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(data));

            return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: But how will I get the data into 'byte[]', for That I have to load the entire downloaded file into memory, which I don't want.

Comment: What magic would you want to do to transfer the `byte[]`??? there's no way!!! You are the driver and your steps are just to transfer the `bytes[]` (in memory at this point) to the input stream of the S3 library...

Comment: @KetanChaudhari I am facing the same problem. Have you found the solution?